# Subract a series of business days from a Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a given START DATE and series of milstones that happen on all business days.  I need to calculate the given DATE based on subtraction of NETWORKDAYS (Business days + Holidays) from the date.  Here is the data:

```
Start Date: (A1) 6/30/2014
```

Business Days to subtract:

```
B1-B3:  

3
5
7
```

In a perfect world, I want to type in this function:  =subtractnetworkdays (6/30/2014-B1)  with the result being (6/27/2014) or if a weekend (6/25/2014).

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(A1,WORKDAY(A1, $B$1 * -1),"")
```

Note that the $B$1 is required so when you copy the formula to other cells, the same amount of business days gets subtracted.  The IF statement has been added to not show **#VALUE!** inside the blank cells.   The cell will remain blank until a date is entered.

Comment: +1 for WORKDAY but I'd suggest text function is not required - simply format cells to show the required date format

Comment: Edit:  Removing superfluous.   Missed that.